# jQuery .addClass() causes error on button elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's wrong with my code?

```
var $slider = $('#gallery-slider');
$slider.addClass('someClass') //works fine
var $buttons = $('.btn-controls');
var $active_btn = $buttons[1];
alert($active_btn); // alert 'object HTMLButtonElement' i.e. element has been taken correctly
$active_btn.addClass('someClass') //causes en error '$active_btn.addClass is not a function'
```

Comment: `var $active_btn = $buttons[1];` returns a dom element reference, `var $active_btn = $buttons.eq(1);`

Comment: instead of `$active_btn.addClass('someClass')` use `$($active_btn).addClass('someClass')`

Comment: thank a lot it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$buttons[1];` doesn't return a jquery object so you cannot invoke jquery methods through it.

Either use

```
$buttons.addClass("someClass") //if you want to add class to all buttons
```

or

```
$buttons.eq(1).addClass("someClass") //if you want to add class to second element in the list of buttons
```

Answer (score 0):

Clean your code with the proper *semicolon*s, and.....you have to pass a [jQuery object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/) to change class. Use the `eq()` [selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
var $slider = $('#gallery-slider');
$slider.addClass('someClass'); //works fine
var $buttons = $('.btn-controls');
var $active_btn = $('.btn-controls').eq(1);
alert($active_btn); // alert 'object HTMLButtonElement' i.e. element has been      taken correctly
$active_btn.addClass('someClass'); //causes en error '$active_btn.addClass is not a function'
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Kartikeya Khosla said, you need to convert the html object to jquery object

```
$($active_btn).addClass('someClass')
```